# Delete Multiple Django Model Attributes

Tags: python, django

How could we clear multiple Django models attributes without having to list each individual attribute in a loop?

```
books = Book.objects.all()
for book in books:
    book.description = None
    book.title = None
    book.etc = None  # other attribute
    book.etc = None  # other attribute
    book.etc = None  # other attribute and etc.
    book.save()
```

Could we use list of string and loop over them? I tried using `getattr` and `book._meta.get_field(field)`, but I can't really get it to clear the attribute.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setattr` function instead of `getattr`:

```
for attr in ('description', 'title', 'etc'):
    setattr(book, attr, None)
book.save()
```

But if you don't do something special in the `save()` method or `*_save` signals then use the @two-bit-alchemist's suggestion:

```
Book.objects.all().update(description=None, title=None, etc=None)
```

Or, if you don't want to repeat the `=None`, you can build a `**kwargs` for `update()`:

```
fields = ('description', 'title', 'etc')
Book.objects.all().update(**{f: None for f in fields})
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a list of all the many-to-many fields in the model. This is to make
it generic. You can also just do the fields by using their actual names.

```
mfields = [] # ManyToMany fields by field_name
metafield = Book._meta.get_fields()
for f in metafield:
    if "'django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField'" in str(type(f)):
        field_name = f[f.rfind('.') + 1:]
        mfields.append(field_name)
```

This works through all your books. For each book it works through all the many-to-many fields. For each field, it gets all the records related to this field and removes them. getattr() is a python built in function.

```
for book in Book.objects.all():
    for field in mfields:
        for y in getattr(book, field).all():
            getattr(book, field).remove(y.id)
```

Comment: Opps, I read multiple as many-to-many, this will work with normal fields too, you just need to make a list to work through them.